# How to manipulate a pandas series with an alternating logic without using for loop?

Tags: python, pandas, series

I have a series comprising only of 1, 0 and -1. I am trying to implement a flipflop logic : 1 can come only after -1 and -1 can come only after a 1. So basically, 1 and -1 have to occur only after they have already occurred.

```
>>> a
[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, -1, 1]
>>> out
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, -1, 1]
```

How can I achieve this using pandas and without using a for loop?
Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### I have taken your list in a panda series to utilize pandas functionality

`a = pd.Series([0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1])`

#### after running the below code it gives the desire output

`a[a.index.difference(a[a!=0][a[a!=0].diff()!=0].index)] = 0`

#### output

`[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`

I hope it would give you the desired solution.